# Trying to understand garbage collection in java

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection, garbage

Trying to understand GC with below piece of code

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //HashMap<String,String> newmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        //CleanUpThread t = new CleanUpThread(newmap);
        ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
        //t.start();
        while(true){

            al.add(Math.random());


            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Since am creating random double objects into a list , i am expecting out of memory error to occur and my heap get filled.

But i see My GC being cleaning up and only ~1Mb of data stays in survivor space.

Running the jvm with 32MB heap size and occupancy % for GC set to 30%.

Can anyone give more explanation on the behavior.[image]

Comment: How long do you conducted an experiment?

Comment: Just keep it running. What happens then?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you didn't appear OutOfMemoryError, becouse objects in your code are created very slow (every 200 ms). Try to remove `sleep` fragment of code.

Secondly, if your GC cleaned data in the survivor space, it doesn't mean that GC remove this objects from the memory. It means, that GC moved these objects to the Old generation, because they survived several garbage collections. You can see, that the size of the Old Generation only grow and no garbage collections happened there.

[image]

When your heap size will be filled, GC will try to clean up objects (you will see the often fluctuations on the GC time chart), but this attempts will be unsuccessful, because it will no objects to delete. Over time, you will receive OME.

I think that if you remove `sleep` fragment of code and wait enough time you will receive OME.

For faster results you can reduce the heap size.

Comment: Thanks for the information. really helped. Also i tried removing al.add(Math.random()); piece of code itself and just keep while loop running. Even in this case i see eden space to be increasing like before. I dont have code running creating objects now, still why would the eden space be increasing ? am confused on this.

Comment: It's a good question. I tried to reproduce your example and made sure that heap size grow. I suggest that it's own JVM objects creation. More than that, when you connect to java process using JVisualVM it's neccessary to allocate some objects for communication between java process and JVisualVM profilers.

Comment: The difference between these two examples is when you ```add``` doubles in the list GC can't clean up objects, but in the empty while loop garbage collections happen great and there is no reason for OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much for the responses. Also i tried taking out the sleep factor from the code. the observation was jvisualVM was not responding at all when tried connecting to this process and eventually java program was killed with OOM GC overhead limit exceeded.

Comment: @kaushikHS when you remove the `sleep`, the JVM will allocate at such a high rate, that connecting to the JVM may fail, as it is not capable of responding. Insert a `sleep` at the beginning, i.e. before the loop, to be able to connect to the JVM, before it enters the heavy allocation loop. Mind that when you have connected to the JVM with a tool like VisualVM, the communication itself will produce garbage as well, so even when you removed all application allocations, there will still be some steady allocation *while monitoring*.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you Eden space is filled, Minor GC runs and it transfers the alive objects to the survivor. After some iteration, the long-lived survivor objects are transferred to the old Generation space.

In your case, minor GC is running whenever the Eden space is exhausted to a percentage and the Old generation size is increasing with time. you can figure this in the graph.

Remove the sleep interval, it will give you a more clear view. Also, you can configure the heap size to analyze better.

For more understanding, you can refer 
https://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-memory-management-in-java